# 'JpegImageFile' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I run into this error towards the end of my script. The error is at the second last line of this code.

```
for key, i in xylist.iteritems():
    foreground = Image.open(a+str(key)[13:-1]+".jpg")
    background = Image.open("newschedule.jpg")
    x= xylist.get(key)[0]
    y= xylist.get(key)[1]
    background.paste(foreground(x,y), foreground)
background.save("newschedule.jpg")      #must use variable
```

Error I receive:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Usersschedule\Scripts\Code\Dictionary + Loop 21.py", line 169, in <module>
    background.paste(foreground(x,y), foreground)
TypeError: 'JpegImageFile' object is not callable
>>>
```

Could someone please let me know how to tackle this error? I've read through some documentations but unable to find anything on this.

Comment: `foreground` is not function - you can't call `foreground(x,y)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.paste

```
paste(image, box)
```

So you probably need

```
background.paste( foreground, (x,y) )
```

-

BTW: in every loop you load background but you don't save it. Maybe you should load background only once - before `for` loop.

Maybe you need:

```
background = Image.open("newschedule.jpg")

for key, (x, y) in xylist.iteritems():
    filename = "%s%s.jpg" % (a, str(key)[13:-1])
    foreground = Image.open(filename)
    background.paste( foreground, (x,y))

background.save("newschedule.jpg")
```